# Get resize mode of WinForm in c#

Tags: c#

Let's say I have the simplest form in c# .NET, and want to resize it.
During the form is resized, how can I get when it is being maximized, and when minimized??
Is there any **`resize mode`** property in any event?

Answer (score 2):

There's a `WindowState` property on the Form object itself. Its value is one of the `FormWindowState` enumerated values: `Normal`, `Minimized`, or `Maximized`. If you check that property in your resize event, will that tell you what you need to know?